# Extract element of a list using pipe() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to extract an element of a list using `pipe()` function and called by name or element number.

```
MyList = list('a' = 4, 'b' = 19)
```

Typically we would use below standard syntax -

```
MyList[['a']]
```

or

```
MyList[[1]]
```

So if I want to use `dplyr::pipe()` then what is the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pluck`

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
MyList %>% 
     pluck('a')
#[1] 4
```

Or

```
MyList %>% 
    pluck(1)
#[1] 4
```

---

Or use the `.$` or `.[[`

```
MyList %>% 
     .$a
#[1] 4
```

---

Or with `extract2` from `magrittr`

```
MyList %>% 
   magrittr::extract2('a')
#[1] 4
```